# How to incude user inputs \n into a textarea when trying to split the input by \n?

Tags: jquery, textarea

I a splitting the input of a `textarea` into seperate lines like this.

```
const lines = $('#myTextarea').val().split('\n');
```

However I would also split it when the user enters `\n` but this is somehow ignored.

So when the user's input in the textarea is:

```
first line \n second line
third line
fourth line
```

I expect to have an array with `[first line,second line, third line, fourth line]`

but instead I get`[first line \n second line, third line, fourth line]`

Comment: From link: use a regex: `$("textarea").val().split(/\n|\\n/)`  (you may want/need to add whitespace trimming to the regex or after)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this simple `regex` - `/\s+/` along with `.trim()` function to get your desired output and to make sure each space or multiple spaces are converted in to each line when using `split()`

**Live Demo:**

```js
function getText() {
  let lines = $('#myTextarea').val().trim().split(/\s+/);
  console.log(lines)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="myTextarea" cols="50" rows="4" placeholder="Enter text"></textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="getText()">
Split 
</button>
```